# Tag do Google AdWords ações de conversão

Tags: javascript, ajax, google

Criando uma campanha no google adwords** tem a parte que precisa validar os cliques se foram efetivados.

Em ferramentas "Ações de conversão" cria se aquele script, que diz o seguinte que deve colocar em sua pagina de sucesso.

Certo!, tranquilo se eu tivesse uma pagina de sucesso, agora vamos aos fatos. é um formulário onde é capturado o e-mail do cliente. usando Ajax, quando ocorreu sucesso na validação do e-mail, ai sim ele deve considerar. sucesso!

- Então na minha mensagem, de sucesso coloco todo o script? onde é disparado esse evento?
- Já testei vários formas essa semana, mas ainda não esta contando os hits corretamente.
- O mais próximo que cheguei, todo o clique que chegava pelo google AdWords, marcava o hit como clique efetivado, mas na verdade ele só deve efetivar se mostrar a mensagem e-mail cadastrado com sucesso.

Image
[image: Configuração]**

- Seguindo a linha, (**não consegui validar ainda**)marquei como certa a respota do "Sorack",
- > Mas ainda não consegui efetivar a solução,
- Assim que eu conseguir validar o processo, vou colocar uma **"Resposta"** na minha própria pergunta,
- Mostrando os passo que precisei adotar para funcionar.
- Mas parece que ninguem sabe!, todos só sabem o trivial,

  > saiu do caminho feliz, 'boooom' todos morrem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar uma `trigger` à sua `tag`.
Uma `trigger` gerencia quando uma `tag` é ativada. Ela é composta por um evento e um ou mais filtros. Cada filtro é composto por **Variável**, **Operador** e **Valor**.

- **Variável:** Escolha entre `url`, `referrer`, etc.
- **Operador:** Escolha entre `equals`, `contains`, etc.
- **Valor:** Valor que será procurado na página.

Você pode utilizar os eventos `Form Submission` ou `Clicks` para o seu caso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A documentação está disponível em **[Triggers](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106961?hl=en&visit_id=1-636159288157786867-479431949&rd=1)**.

**EDIT 1**

Esta é a imagem do cadastro de `trigger` preenchido para um formulário:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Isso esta muito vago, Qual a ferramenta do google tem isso?
no link que postou, https://www.google.com/analytics/tag-manager/
mais ai pede "SIGN UP FOR FREE", é isso mesmo até quando vou poder usar o serviço, vai me cobrar depois?

Nesse caso, vou um evento tipo "Custom Events"?

Comment: O link do Google [Tag Manager](https://tagmanager.google.com/) é esse aqui e o evento é `WEB`.

Comment: Até estou conseguindo interagir agora. Mas quanto mais eu vejo, mais pergunta aprece, não daria de ser mais objetivo?

Comment: @MarceloFerreira sem saber a sua estrutura do `form` e tudo mais é bem difícil. A ferramenta que você quer é a `trigger`, você só tem que selecionar o evento `Form Submission (WEB)` e filtrar o seu `form`. Não tem muito segredo. Depois é só vincular essa sua `trigger` a sua `tag`no `adwords`

Comment: hum.. parece simples, deve ser porque não estou acostumado com essa linguajar.
Exemplo isso => 
"Event name" que nome de evento é esse esta relacionado a uma sintaxe deles, ou é um simples caption, esta relacionado ao DOM, Javascript, entende, sou desenvolvedor, e sei se as coisas vão sendo jogadas no ar no final não vai dar certo.

Comment: @MarceloFerreira adicionei mais uma imagem de como ficaria um cadastro desse. É bem simples, tá difícil deixar mais claro que isso

Comment: Quando tento exportar o trigger, analisando o código dela tem uma detalhe que acho que não esta certo.

 "tagManagerUrl": "localhost:9001/#/container/accounts/65656565/containers/656565/workspaces?apiLink=container"

Comment: @MarceloFerreira localhost?

Comment: é olha como gerou esse código localhost:9001.
não deveria ser meu host?

Comment: @MarceloFerreira Printa a tela do acionador que vc criou pra eu ver

Comment: Postei a imagem, na pergunta

Comment: @MarceloFerreira então Marcelo, parece que tá correto, agora tem que colocar o acionador na sua `tag` e testar

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49299/discussion-between-marcelo-ferreira-and-sorack).

Comment: Ainda não consegui, validar isso, mas adotei uma linha recomendada pelo google, mas até o momento ainda a questão esta sem resolver. o processo é longo ainda não projetou uma linha de sucesso